# When to use models and migrations in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1. rails g migration MigrationName
2. rails g model MigrationName

I know these two commands. I am confused when to use which command as function of both look similar.

Also how those files created by them are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `rails g model ModelName` then you'll get a result similar to the following:

```
rails g model User        

      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20200430143738_create_users.rb
      create    app/models/user.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/user_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/users.yml
```

As you see, it creates a model file (in this case `User`), the migration file automatically named as `create_yourmodelname_plural`, plus a test file and a fixture for the model.

On the other hand, if you run `rails g migration MigrationName`, you are just creating a migration file. So, if you were to create a user table, you'll get a similar result:

```
 rails g migration CreateUsers 

      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20200430144301_create_users.rb
```

In conclusion, the first case can be used when you do not have a model nor the corresponding table in the database: you can easily create both a model file and a migration file with this automatically prefilled content (in this example the model is `User`):

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
    end
  end
end
```

The second case is used instead for specifically creating just a migration file -  for any purpose (updating or even deleting a table, for instance), not only the creation of a new table.

I hope this can help :)

Comment: And how these two file that is db/migrate/20200430143738_create_users.rb and app/models/user.rb work differently?

Answer (score 0):

Well the main difference is that the second one should be rails g model ModelName doesn't just create a migration, but also creates a model file and a spec file for that model. It also will most generate a create table migration, whereas with rails g migration MigrationName, you can just do very specific migrations such as adding an index, or adding/removing columns. Sections 2.1 and 2.2 will help you get a better grasp: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html